# Continuous Functions and neighborhood

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity

Let $f: \Bbb{R} \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ be continuous and let $\beta \in \Bbb{R}$. Show that if $x_0 \in \Bbb{R}$ is such that $f(x_0) < \beta$, then there exist a $\delta$ - neighborhood $V$ of $x_0$ such that $f(x)  < \beta$ for all $x \in V$

**My Proof:**

Suppose $f(x_0) < \beta$

Let $f: \Bbb{R} \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ be continuous

then $lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} f(x) = f(x_0)$

By the definition of limits, we see that $\exists V_{\beta-f(x_0)}(x_0)$ of $x_0$ s.t

$|f(x)-f(x_0)| < \beta - f(x_0)$ for any $x \in V_{\beta-f(x_0)}(x_0)$

therefore $f(x) - f(x_0) < \beta - f(x_0)$ for any $x \in V_{\beta-f(x_0)}(x_0)$

Furthermore we obtain $f(x) < \beta \forall x \in V_{\beta-f(x_0)}(x_0)$

Answer (score 0):

You have more or less the right idea, assuming I have understood your notation correctly. I have presented a cleaner proof below.

The correct definition of continuity (at $x_0$) to use here is *for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\varepsilon$ whenever $|x-x_0|<\delta$*.

Since $f(x_0)<\beta$, we can set $\varepsilon:=\beta-f(x_0)>0$. Now, since $f$ is continuous at $x_0$, choose $\delta>0$ such that, for all $x\in\mathbb R$ with $|x-x_0|<\delta$, we have $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\varepsilon$. In particular, for each $x$ with $|x-x_0|<\delta$, we have $f(x)<f(x_0)+\varepsilon$. In particular $f(x)<\beta$ for all such $x$.

(Take $V=(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$ to finish.)

Answer (score 0):

Consider $\epsilon$ small enough so that $f(x_0) < f(x_0) + \epsilon < \beta$. By continuity of $f$, we have a $\delta$ neighbourhood such that for all $x$ within the neighbourhood, $f(x_0)<f(x)<f(x_0) + \epsilon< \beta$. QED.

Answer (score 0):

Because $f$ is continuous in $x_0$, let $\varepsilon = \beta - f(x_0) > 0$. Then there exists $\delta > 0$ such that

$$\mid x - x_0 \mid \ < \ \delta \ \Rightarrow \ \mid f(x) - f(x_0) \mid \ < \beta - f(x_0)$$

$$\Leftrightarrow - \beta + f(x_0) < f(x) - f(x_0) < \beta - f(x_0)$$

$$\Leftrightarrow - \beta + 2f(x_0) < f(x) < \beta,$$

for all $x \in (x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta)$.